# Add alt text in google.maps.MarkerImage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, accessibility, google-maps-markers

I have an application that uses google maps. The application works fine, however when use [WAVE tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wave-evaluation-tool/jbbplnpkjmmeebjpijfedlgcdilocofh) to check the web accessibility, it shows the application has nine missing alternative text. After study the code, I guess my javascript function occurs the errors.

Thanks geocodezip let me know that the MarkerImage was deprecated in v3.10, so I modified the code. However The WAVE result still shows the same web accessibility issue. May I know which part I make the mistake for the Icon part please?

```
//previous code is removed as the MarkerImage was deprecated in v3.10
//so the code has been modified 
g_1Icon = {
    url: IMG_MARKER_1,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_1,
    size: new google.maps.Size(52, 29),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};
g_2Icon = {
    url: IMG_MARKER_2,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
    // icon: IMG_MARKER_2,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};
g_3Icon = {
    IMG_MARKER_3,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_3,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};

g_4Icon = {
    url: IMG_MARKER_4,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_4,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};
    
g_5Icon = {
    url: IMG_MARKER_5,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_5,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'       
};

g_6Icon = {
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_6,
    url: IMG_MARKER_6,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};

g_7Icon ={
    url: IMG_MARKER_7,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_7,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};

g_8Icon ={
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_8,
    url: IMG_MARKER_8,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};

g_9Icon = {
    url: IMG_MARKER_9,
    //also try but not work the WAVE still displays the web 
    accessibility issue.
   // icon: IMG_MARKER_9,
    size: new google.maps.Size(21, 31),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 31),
    title:'put alt text here'
};
```

I try to find more information about the WAVE result, it shows these images missing alternative text.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22none%22%20d%3D%22M0%200h24v24H0V0z%22/%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%20d%3D%22M12.06%209.06l4-4-4-4-1.41%201.41%201.59%201.59h-.18c-2.3%200-4.6.88-6.35%202.64-3.52%203.51-3.52%209.21%200%2012.72%201.5%201.5%203.4%202.36%205.36%202.58v-2.02c-1.44-.21-2.84-.86-3.95-1.97-2.73-2.73-2.73-7.17%200-9.9%201.37-1.37%203.16-2.05%204.95-2.05h.17l-1.59%201.59%201.41%201.41zm8.94%203c-.19-1.74-.88-3.32-1.91-4.61l-1.43%201.43c.69.92%201.15%202%201.32%203.18H21zm-7.94%207.92V22c1.74-.19%203.32-.88%204.61-1.91l-1.43-1.43c-.91.68-2%201.15-3.18%201.32zm4.6-2.74l1.43%201.43c1.04-1.29%201.72-2.88%201.91-4.61h-2.02c-.17%201.18-.64%202.27-1.32%203.18z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">

<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2018%2016%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23666%22%20d%3D%22M0%2016h8V9H0v7zm10%200h8V9h-8v7zM0%207h8V0H0v7zm10-7v7h8V0h-8z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E" style="width: 18px;">
```

I search it from the code but it does not exist in the application (I don't find the code that use those images). So does it mean those images are generated by the google map?

Grateful if someone can give some advices about this issue or let me know my mistakes please. Thank you.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#convertingtoicon
[Marker off-set on Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083707/marker-off-set-on-google-map-api-v3)

[Google maps API: Marker image positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318795/google-maps-api-marker-image-positioning)

[google-map tiles missing alt tag causing lower accessibility score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714153/google-map-tiles-missing-alt-tag-causing-lower-accessibility-score)

https://litzdigital.com/blog/making-google-maps-controls-more-accessible/

https://www.javatpoint.com/jquery-attr

Comment: `MarkerImage` was deprecated in v3.10 (a really long time ago, [Marker off-set on Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083707/marker-off-set-on-google-map-api-v3),. Use the `Icon` anonymous object instead). Adding a `title` to the marker should give you text on `mouseover`.

Comment: @geocodezip, thank you very much for me know the information. I read the post and to use `icon` for add the title but the WAVE result still shows the same web accessibility (missing alternative text). Would you mind let me know my mistakes please. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding to the WAVE result it shows the images are missing alternative text, however I don't find the function that calls those images. So do those images generated by the google map? If so, is it possible to say that web accessibility is a false alarm?

Comment: Currently, there is no way to add alt text for marker images. You may want to look at the open feature request in Google Maps Platform Public Issue Tracker about adding alt text on markers. I can also recommend that you add additional details regarding this. You can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213261447